# How to add dynamic Texbox in GridView at RunTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I would like to add controls like textBox in GridView from code on the fly.

In my project i have one Grid in that i can't decide how many rows and columns are there. so that i just give it DataSource. This working fine.

```
GridView G = new GridView();
G.DataSourse = dt;
G.DataBind();
```

now i want to do such thing that in `Gridview` all the controls are `Textbox` control so that i can write in that textbox.

```
TextBox t= new TextBox();
G.Contorls.Add(t);
```

This will throw exception...

do anyone have any idea about this???

Thanks in advance..

Regards
Amit Vyas

Comment: @ amit what exception is it throwing could you please post that and also in what event of gridview you are trying to add textbox to the gridview controls collection

Comment: @Devjosh exception is object ref is not set to instance of an object.

Comment: at any time i would like to add control before bind datatable to Grid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it in design time with ItemTemplate

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GrdDynamic" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Name" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**EDIT**

Here is an interesting CodeProject post on [dynamically adding template columns](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13462/How-to-create-template-columns-dynamically-in-a-gr)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/708.html link and use below code:

```
 DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();

        ddl.Visible = true;

        ddl.ID = "ddl1";

        ddl.Items.Add("Item1");

        TableCell cell = new TableCell();      

        gv.Rows[0].Cells.Add(cell);

        gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(ddl);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking a way to add TextBox dynamically in the existing GridView, then using RowDataBound event of the GridView would be best solution.

**Add a PlaceHolder control in the ItemTemplate field.**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GrdDynamic" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat='server' ID="PlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

public void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //find placeholder control
    PlaceHolder placeHolder = e.Row.FindControl("PlaceHolder1") as PlaceHolder;

    TextBox TextBox1 = new TextBox();
    placeHolder.Controls.Add(TextBox1);      
}
```

Comment: i appreciate your code logic. its too easy but in that there is only one Column but in my case there is no fixed columns. i can't decide number of column.. now how can i do that thing???